# Kali Linux - wlan0 not showing up in ifconfig, does virtual machine affect this?

Tags: kali-linux

I have Panda Wireless PAU07 - the seller says it is supporting Kali and Promiscuous/Monitor modes. However I am running on a virtual machine and when running `ifconfig` wlan0 or other interfaces do not show up. Is this because I am running on virtual machine, should I switch to live USB?

Comment: Do you see more with `ifconfig -a`?

Comment: @eblock I've gotten it fixed now, had to install an extension pack

Answer (score 1):

In VirtualBox VM, there is a USB devices menu; just add your device there, then install the extension pack from the VirtualBox website, and it should be all set up.